# Why doesn't the folder path (public_html to public_shtml) change when I add the ssl-certificate in the VestaCP panel?

Tags: bash, vesta

I add the certificate in the VestaCP panel, I restart Nginx but in the configuration file
`/home/admin/conf/web/%domain%.nginx.ssl.conf`

still the same
`root        /home/admin/web/%domain%/public_html;`

although in the template

`/usr/local/vesta/data/templates/web/nginx/php-fpm/default.stpl`

exactly `root        %sdocroot%;`

in the bash script that changes this

`usr/local/vesta/func/domain.sh`

I found

```
# Update web domain values
prepare_web_domain_values() {
    if [[ "$domain" = *[![:ascii:]]* ]]; then
        domain_idn=$(idn -t --quiet -a $domain)
    else
        domain_idn=$domain
    fi
    group="$user"
    email="info@$domain"
    docroot="$HOMEDIR/$user/web/$domain/public_html"
    sdocroot="$docroot"
    if [ "$SSL_HOME" = 'single' ]; then
        sdocroot="$HOMEDIR/$user/web/$domain/public_shtml" ;
    fi
```

But I never figured out how it checks
`"$SSL_HOME" = 'single'`

Thank you so much in advance for the answers!